# jQuery background colour animate toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle animation of background colour on click (along with form slideToggle), but the first click hides the element (a#opt4) instead of changing the colour. What am I doing wrong?

note: when I'm running single background animate, instead of toggle, it works no problem. I want to remove the colour when user clicks on a link again, though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#contact form').hide();

            $('a#opt4').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $('#contact form').slideToggle();

                $(this).toggle(function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: "#99ccff"},500);
                    },
                    function() {
                        $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: "none"},500);
                    });

            });
        });
```

Comment: can you show a fiddle or share the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What jQuery version are you using? As of jQuery 1.8 [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated, and 1.9 [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)  was removed.

Just so people aren't confused about the [toggle animation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) as apposed to the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.

If you are using 1.9 or above you can try writing your own toggle functionality. Of course this method is basic and could be built upon.

```
$.fn.toggleState = function (even, odd) {
    this.toggled = this.data('toggled') || false;

    if (!toggled) {
        if (typeof even === 'function') {
            even(this);
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof odd === 'function') {
            odd(this);
        }
    }

    this.data({ toggled: !this.toggled });
};
```

Which can be used like so

```
$('a#opt4').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).toggleState(function (el) {
        el.animate({
            backgroundColor: "#99ccff"
        }, 500);
    }, function (el) {
        el.animate({
            backgroundColor: "none"
        }, 500);
    });
});

$.fn.toggleState = function (even, odd) {
    this.toggled = this.data('toggled') || false;

    if (!this.toggled) {
        if (typeof even === 'function') {
            even(this);
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof odd === 'function') {
            odd(this);
        }
    }

    this.data({ toggled: !this.toggled });
};
```

Check it out in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjG7p/)

Just a side note, you can also use jQueryUI to animate background color. Which is what's used in the demo.

Comment: fantastic. that's EXACTLY what I was looking for. didn't realise toggle has been removed ! thanks very very much mate

Answer (score 1):

Use classes to do that...

In css:

```
.active-link{ 
      background-color: #99ccff;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

In your JS:

```
$(this).toogleClass("active-link");
```

Comment: but then I can't animate the color, can I ?

Comment: Agreed there is no way to animate the color property using this method.

Comment: I need IE8 support, though

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/animate/ you cannot animate background colors.

From the docs

background-color cannot be - animated -, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)

I've not used it but here is the color plugin they mention.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

Comment: yeah I'm using the plugin alright, as I mentioned before bg animation works on it's own, just the toggle doesn't

Comment: I think a fiddle would help. here.