# Fade animation for an element, which also uses: display:none unless in hover state

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bubble box which shows in 2 cases:

1. when hovered (right away, with no animation)
2. 5 seconds after page load (unless user already hovered it), and it will also disappear after 5 seconds. it will also have X close button in this case.

In case #2, I want it to show/disappear with fade in/out animation (also for X button).

I've tried making the animation with Jquery, using `opacity` change instead of `display:block/none`, (see commented code in jquery) and accordingly, modified the CSS to have `opacity:0` and `display:block` instead of `none`.

However, once I make this modification, the bubble will not work anymore in case #1, since it is already "displayed" but with zero opacity".

What would be the best practice to solve all this? maybe I shouldn't make the animation in Jquery, but rather use some CSS3 effect, but I couldn't get it to work properly either.

HTML:

```
<div style="width:300px;margin-left: 200px;">
<span class="st-help parent-span" >
  <div class="cta-wrapper">                         
      <div class="button-like">Hover me for info
        <div class="st-help-text st-cta">
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        </div>        
    </div>
  </div>           
</span>
<span id="buttonx" class="buttonx">X</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.st-help {
    position: relative;
    cursor: help
}

.st-help .st-help-text {
    display: none;/**/
    background-color: #FDFCEF;
    border: 1px solid #E8E5C1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: calc(100% + 7px);
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left

    /*   opacity:0;*/
}

.st-help .st-help-text:after,
.st-help .st-help-text:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 55%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none
}

.st-help .st-help-text:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #FDFCEF;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px
}

.st-help .st-help-text:before {
    border-color: transition transition #E8E5C1;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-bottom-color: #E8E5C1
}

.st-help:hover .st-help-text {
    display: block!important

}

.st-help-text {
    width: 185px

}




.st-help .st-cta {
    padding: 7px;
    left: -20px;
    top: calc(100% + 9px);
    font-size: 13px
}

.st-cta {
    width: 255px
}

.parent-span .cta-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    display: inline-block
}

.button-like:hover {
    background-color: #aaa!important
}

.button-like {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f07c00;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: .4em 2.1em .4em .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    letter-spacing: -.01em
}

.st-help .st-cta {
    left: -50px;
    top: calc(100% + 14px)
}

.buttonx {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: none; /**/
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 52px;
    left: 6px;
    color: #a2a087;
    font-size: 1.1em;

/*   opacity:0;*/

}
```

Jquery:

```
var flag = true;
$(".button-like").hover(function(){
    flag = false;
})
$( document ).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
if(flag)
{
        $( ".st-help-text" ).css( "display", "block" );
    //  $(".st-help-text").animate({opacity:1},1000);

        $(".button-like").css("background-color", "#aaa");
        $('#buttonx').css("display","block");
//      $('#buttonx').animate({opacity:1},1000);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $( ".st-help-text" ).css( "display", "none" );
            //$(".st-help-text").animate({opacity:0},1000);
    $('#buttonx').css("display","none");
    //$('#buttonx').animate({opacity:0},1000);
            $(".button-like").css("background-color", "#f07c00");
        }, 4000); 
}   
    }, 3000);
});

$( "#buttonx" ).click(function() {
    $( ".st-help-text" ).css( "display", "none" );
$('#buttonx').css("display","none");
    $(".button-like").css("background-color", "#f07c00");
});
```

P.S, I also want `button-like` to change back to `#f07c00` with a transition, if I use the fade effect for the bubble box.

Comment: did you try .fadeIn(), .fadeOut() or .fadeToggle()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eklimcz/u98Zw/, http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2w2f2/, http://jsfiddle.net/kslagdive/hAkLM/ can these help you?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't, and it seems to solve this. any ideas about the color change of `button-like` to be also in transition, according with fading speed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980239/jquery-background-colour-animate-toggle I hope this should help you for toggling color in an animated way!